# Install two server instances with install4j

Tags: install4j

I need to install two server instances with different applications in each.
Is the recommended approach to create both servers with applications in distribution tree?

Is it possible to pack one server instance and applications and create from it two server instances with different applications each during installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the "Install a service" action you can install two service instances of the same executable. However, you cannot select the executable directly in the "Service" property.

Instead, select `[Other service executable]` from that drop-down, then fill in the "Executable" and "Name" properties. In the "Name" property of the second "Install a service" action choose a different service name than in the first one.

Comment: There is also need to configure a separate CATALINA_BASE for each service in case of Tomcat